# What is meaning of low latency high volume systems/applications?

Tags: java, web-applications

In many Job descriptions for a Java developer , I see this line : Experience of working on low latency , high volume systems/applications? what is the exact meaning of this sentence?

Comment: The EXACT meaning you would have to ask the person asking it. I can imagine it regards systems with heavy throughput which have to be able to cope with that within a set timeframe. Realtime systems and/or applications with lots of concurrent users.

Comment: I think Gimby got it right, sounds like a Socket job.

Comment: Yes I think I got it now. An example can be a gaming application with multiple users, scientific data processing application etc...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Low latency*: Fast response time from individual requests. Usually means that you know about optimizing database queries, data caching, pipelining, etc.

*High volume*: Many requests, typically thousands per second. Usually means that you know about large-scale multithreading, distributed databases, data and session caching, etc.

Comment: I agree. So requirement would typically require similar kind of optimization and so they require working experience in this. Thanks for the reply.